# How can I rebuild a source jar from another one?

Tags: java

I've got a **tool-jar** and its source jar file.

There's something wrong in his/her code when I'm using it in my code, so I'd like to change some of his/her code and rebuild it to a  tool-jar.

The tool-jar is just like `Apache Commons`, which is **not executable**. Could anyone tell me how to handle it either in command line or eclipse?

I've tried to import Existing projects into workspace in Eclipse, but when I choose the `XXX-source.jar`, there is no project in it so I cannot click the finish button.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' not sure you could just go and change this dependency just like that. You should discuss the issue with him/her, maybe then he/she wants to make a new version of that jar and publish it. And what about others who use this jar too? should they keep working with the old one or get the new one too?

Anyway, to answer your question, a jar file is just zip file, just unpack it somewhere, import the source code into eclipse (create a new project and make it point to that directory), make your changes, compile and export it again. Make sure you export both `tools.jar` for compile and run time and `tools-source.jar`. Also if you want to make changes to source it is advisable to have it version controlled.

Comment: He didn't update this jar since 2011, and this is the only suitable jar for me as far as I've googled. so I have to work on my own to change the source. :)

Comment: @Judking, cool, then proceed as I described, and put the source code in version control so that you can retrace the changes you have done!

Comment: Succeed, Thanks bro~!

Answer (score 0):

Simply unpack source jar and after this compile source back to jar.

THis can help: [Maven compile a source jar dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432549/maven-compile-a-source-jar-dependency)

Comment: Is there any way for just unpacking the source jar, changing the code and rebuilding it to a tool-jar?

Comment: Check if this jar has pom.xml inside (in META-INF directory)

Answer (score -1):

You need JAD (JAva Decompiler). This is a magical tool and is available [here](http://varaneckas.com/jad/).

Comment: He has source jar file :)